# Flutter dart not a constant expression, unexpected kernel tag error

Tags: mysql, dart, flutter

I am making a simple app using Flutter and would like to connect to a mysql databse. The plugin I am using as a driver for the dart codes is [here](https://github.com/dart-db/sqljocky5).

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
    [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4789): 'package:sqljocky5/src/buffered_socket.dart': error: Not a constant expression: unexpected kernel tag InvalidExpression (19)
E/flutter ( 4789): #0      Connection.connect (package:sqljocky5/src/connection.dart:124:20)
E/flutter ( 4789): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Catching the error yields the same error:

```
I/flutter ( 4789): opening connection
I/flutter ( 4789): connection open
I/flutter ( 4789): running example
I/flutter ( 4789): dropping tables
I/flutter ( 4789): 'package:sqljocky5/src/buffered_socket.dart': error: Not a constant expression: unexpected kernel tag InvalidExpression (19)
```

The method used to instantiate the connection is a copied from the driver's github example:

```
class Example {
  ConnectionPool pool;

  Example(this.pool);

  Future run() async {
    // drop the tables if they already exist
    await dropTables();
    print("dropped tables");
    // then recreate the tables
    await createTables();
    print("created tables");
    // add some data
    await addData();
    // and read it back out
    await readData();
  }

  Future dropTables() {
    print("dropping tables");
    var dropper = new TableDropper(pool, ['pets', 'people']);
    return dropper.dropTables();
  }

  Future createTables() {
    print("creating tables");
    var querier = new QueryRunner(pool, [
      'create table people (id integer not null auto_increment, '
          'name varchar(255), '
          'age integer, '
          'primary key (id))',
      'create table pets (id integer not null auto_increment, '
          'name varchar(255), '
          'species text, '
          'owner_id integer, '
          'primary key (id),'
          'foreign key (owner_id) references people (id))'
    ]);
    print("executing queries");
    return querier.executeQueries();
  }

  Future addData() async {
    var query =
        await pool.prepare("insert into people (name, age) values (?, ?)");
    print("prepared query 1");
    var parameters = [
      ["Dave", 15],
      ["John", 16],
      ["Mavis", 93]
    ];
    await query.executeMulti(parameters);

    print("executed query 1");
    query = await pool
        .prepare("insert into pets (name, species, owner_id) values (?, ?, ?)");

    print("prepared query 2");
    parameters = [
      ["Rover", "Dog", 1],
      ["Daisy", "Cow", 2],
      ["Spot", "Dog", 2]
    ];
//          ["Spot", "D\u0000og", 2]];
    await query.executeMulti(parameters);

    print("executed query 2");
  }

  Future readData() async {
    print("querying");
    var result =
        await pool.query('select p.id, p.name, p.age, t.name, t.species '
            'from people p '
            'left join pets t on t.owner_id = p.id');
    print("got results");
    return result.forEach((row) {
      if (row[3] == null) {
        print("ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}, Age: ${row[2]}, No Pets");
      } else {
        print(
            "ID: ${row[0]}, Name: ${row[1]}, Age: ${row[2]}, Pet Name: ${row[3]}, Pet Species ${row[4]}");
      }
    });
  }
}

main() async {
  // OptionsFile options = new OptionsFile('connection.options');
  String user = "root";
  String password = "password";
  int port = 3306;
  String db = "db1";
  String host = "localhost";

  // create a connection
  print("opening connection");
  var pool = new ConnectionPool(
      host: host, port: port, user: user, password: password, db: db, max: 1);
  print("connection open");
  // create an example class
  var example = new Example(pool);
  // run the example
  print("running example");
  await example.run();
  // finally, close the connection
  print("K THNX BYE!");
  pool.closeConnectionsNow();
}
```

I suspect that this might have something to do with Dart 2's inclusion in Flutter recently which breaks this driver. I would like to try and fix this plugin, but I am not sure where to start and what exactly the error denotes.

Comment: I doubt you want to run a MySQL database server instance on your mobile device and also that you want to connect to a MySQL server instance over the internet directly, so using SqlJocky in Flutter is probably not what you want to do. Usually you would use SqlJocky on a Dart server application that provides a REST API that you connect to from Flutter.

Comment: I understand now, so the database will be abstracted away from me by means of a dart server application? So the flutter app will instead use http requests to retrieve data? Is it possible to use a different language, say Java, for the server script instead?

Comment: Not sure if "abstracted away" is a good way to explain that but it's not entirely wrong ;-). It's basically a security measure. Full access to SQL databases often opens a way for a hacker to take over the whole server, therefore only a REST API (or similar) is made available to a public IP address with an API surface as small as possible to make it less like to introduce security holes, and the API then delegates to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

`Not a constant expression` error is usually thrown when a `const` constructor is incorrectly used. Removing the `const` keyword that you've used should solve the issue. But since the error was thrown from the plugin that you're using, try upgrading to the latest version and see if the issue has been fixed.